# is there anyway to interact with flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, xpath, automation

I'm doing automation test and I need to interact with a flash object, I use capybara(ruby), seems it can't deal with flash, anyone knows other way to interact with it?
I think maybe javascript/jquery works, but I don't know how to use it

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="VitrueDomainsMain" data="https://pubapps.s3.amazonaws.com/staging/swf/VitrueDomainsMain.swf?debug=1?1401982078" width="100%" height="100%">
     <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
     <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
     <param name="quality" value="best">          
     <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
     <param name="xiRedirectUrl" value="http://publisher.staging.ey.vitrue.com">
     <param name="redirectUrl" value="">
     <param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
     <param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
     <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
     <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
     <param name="flashvars" value="site_url=http://publisher.staging.ey.vitrue.com&amp;client=2316">
</object>
```

Comment: You'll need to expand on your question a bit for someone to be able to help you. What are you trying to achieve by interacting with the flash object? What "interactions" do you require? What platforms/devices are you targeting, etc...

Comment: You can probably squeeze [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) somehow in there. It works for *anything you see*, but it uses images that you have to take. You will have to see it. If you're using a headless browser, this is out of the question.

Comment: Sikuli needs Jruby, but our project using normal ruby... so may be not fit us.

Comment: I need to interact with a flash to test the flash, but I don't know how to do, is javascript able to do this thing? or I need to use other tools>?